# Can't upload application to google play

Tags: android, google-play

When I create application in Eclipse, I use default designer, and get application in namespace:

> com.example.MyName

Now I try to upload app to Google Play, but getting error "Package Name "com.example" unacceptable. Please try another."

If I change name to com.MyName, I get a lot of error, like:

> R cannot be resolved to a variable

What can I do?

Comment: Once you change package name, make sure you change it to AndroidManifest.xml too.

Comment: I think you mean upload, not download.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to change the package in at least 2, maybe more places depending on how complex your app is:

1. Change the package in the `package` attribute of the `<manifest>` element in your `AndroidManifest.xml`.
2. Change the package name in the `src` folder by right clicking on the old package, Going to `Refactor` -> `Rename` and typing in the same name you used in #1.
3. Beyond that, if your XML files use custom Views, you will need to update their class name as well. Additionally, you will need to update any other place where you've used a fully qualified domain name, like when launching an Intent from a component name.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure your manifest is up to date.
Make sure your source code moved to the correct package.
Clean your project (Project > Clean). it will recompile your code and the R.java file.

Answer (score 0):

Google Play does not accept the default `com.example` package name (to prevent everyone is going to use it, I suppose). Changing it to `com` is even worse!

Use a package with your name, company, application name, nickname, etc. to come up with something *unique*.

When you change the package of a class, you need to update the `import`-statements **to** the class and **in** the class (and possible other references to it, like the ones in the AndroidManifest.xml).

Just to be sure: you can *clean your project* to regenerate the automatically generated source files and recompile all classes.